# SASL Authentication Failed on Postfix as relay server with office365

Tags: authentication, office365, postfix-mta

I'm setting a postfix server as relay to an account in office 365.

I configure the main file /etc/postfix/main.cf as follows:

```
relayhost = [smtp.office365.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
#smtp_tls_security_level = secure
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_secure_cert_match = nexthop
#Check that this path exists -- these are the certificates used by TLS
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
#Set the sasl options
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
sender_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

Also made a sasl_password file:

```
[smtp.office365.com]:587 username@domain.com:thepassword
```

And applied the postmap command:

```
postmap sasl_passwd
```

The messages are not delivered and log show the next message

```
Aug 29 11:22:04 relaysmtp postfix/error[13501]: 0CA2C82CD1: to=<username@domain.com>, relay=none, delay=6538, delays=6538/0/0/0.01, dsn=4.7.3, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: SASL authentication failed; server smtp.office365.com[40.102.32.146] said: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [PT1sdsaoPP.akpr0.prod.outlook.com])
```

The postfix version is 3.2.3 in a CentOS 6.10

I configured the Postfix's log to more verbose output; then i tested with Telnet command from another host.
I'll paste the primitive and the output from postfix separate by signs:

```
telnet 192.168.0.10 25
Trying 192.168.0.10...
Connected to 192.168.0.10.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 **************************************

Sep  4 18:28:37 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: < unknown[192.168.0.15]: quit
Sep  4 18:28:37 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 221 2.0.0 Bye
Sep  4 18:28:37 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: unknown ~? 0.0.0.0/0
Sep  4 18:28:37 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 192.168.0.15 ~? 0.0.0.0/0
Sep  4 18:28:37 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.0.15] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Sep  4 18:28:37 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: master_notify: status 1
Sep  4 18:28:37 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: connection closed
Sep  4 18:28:37 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: proxymap stream disconnect
Sep  4 18:28:37 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: rewrite stream disconnect
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: connection established
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: master_notify: status 0
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: name_mask: resource
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: name_mask: software
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: connect from unknown[192.168.0.15]
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: 192.168.0.15: no match
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: 192.168.0.15: no match
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: smtp_stream_setup: maxtime=300 enable_deadline=0
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_hostname: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: unknown ~? 0.0.0.0/0
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_hostaddr: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: 192.168.0.15 ~? 0.0.0.0/0
Sep  4 18:28:46 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 220 relay.domain.com ESMTP Postfix
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ehlo localhost
250-relay.domain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN

Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: < unknown[192.168.0.15]: ehlo localhost
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: 192.168.0.15: no match
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250-relay.domain.comhos
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250-PIPELINING
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250-SIZE 10240000
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250-VRFY
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250-ETRN
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250-8BITMIME
Sep  4 18:29:44 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250 DSN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mail from: <username@domain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok

Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: < unknown[192.168.0.15]: mail from: <username@domain.com>
Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: extract_addr: input: <username@domain.com>
Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=username@domain.com
Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key ?username@domain.com
Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: extract_addr: in: <username@domain.com>, result: username@domain.com
Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: smtpd_check_rewrite: trying: permit_inet_interfaces
Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: permit_inet_interfaces: unknown 192.168.0.15
Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: fsspace: .: block size 4096, blocks free 2121461
Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: smtpd_check_queue: blocks 4096 avail 2121461 min_free 0 msg_size_limit 10240000
Sep  4 18:33:21 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250 2.1.0 Ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rcpt to: <otheruser@testmail.com>

Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: < unknown[192.168.0.15]: rcpt to: <otheruser@testmail.com>
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: extract_addr: input: <otheruser@testmail.com>
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=otheruser@testmail.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: connect to subsystem private/rewrite
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr request = rewrite
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr rule = local
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr address = username@domain.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: flags
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: 0
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: address
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: username@domain.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: (end)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: rewrite_clnt: local: username@domain.com -> username@domain.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr request = rewrite
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr rule = local
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr address = otheruser@testmail.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: flags
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: 0
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: address
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: otheruser@testmail.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: (end)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: rewrite_clnt: local: otheruser@testmail.com -> otheruser@testmail.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr request = resolve
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr sender = username@domain.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr address = otheruser@testmail.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: flags
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: 0
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: transport
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: transport
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: smtp
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: nexthop
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: nexthop
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: [smtp.office365.com]:587
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: recipient
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: recipient
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: otheruser@testmail.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: flags
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: 4096
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: (end)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: resolve_clnt: `username@domain.com' -> `otheruser@testmail.com' -> transp=`smtp' host=`[smtp.office365.com]:587' rcpt=`otheruser@testmail.com' flags= class=default
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: ctable_locate: install entry key username@domain.com?otheruser@testmail.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: extract_addr: in: <otheruser@testmail.com>, result: otheruser@testmail.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: >>> START Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: permit_mynetworks: unknown 192.168.0.15
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_hostname: mynetworks: unknown ~? 0.0.0.0/0
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_hostaddr: mynetworks: 192.168.0.15 ~? 0.0.0.0/0
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: smtpd_acl_permit: checking smtpd_log_access_permit_actions settings
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: permit_mynetworks: no match
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: smtpd_acl_permit: smtpd_log_access_permit_actions: no match
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks status=1
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: >>> END Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: >>> CHECKING Recipient address VALIDATION MAPS <<<
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key username@domain.com?otheruser@testmail.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: maps_find: recipient_canonical_maps: otheruser@testmail.com: not found
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_string: mydestination: testmail.com ~? relay.domain.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_string: mydestination: testmail.com ~? localhost.domain.comf
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_string: mydestination: testmail.com ~? localhost
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: testmail.com: no match
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: maps_find: recipient_canonical_maps: @testmail.com: not found
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: mail_addr_find: otheruser@testmail.com -> (not found)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: maps_find: canonical_maps: otheruser@testmail.com: not found
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_string: mydestination: testmail.com ~? relay.domain.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_string: mydestination: testmail.com ~? localhost.domain.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_string: mydestination: testmail.com ~? localhost
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: testmail.com: no match
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: maps_find: canonical_maps: @testmail.com: not found
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: mail_addr_find: otheruser@testmail.com -> (not found)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: maps_find: virtual_alias_maps: otheruser@testmail.com: not found
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_string: mydestination: testmail.com ~? relay.domain.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_string: mydestination: testmail.com ~? localhost.domain.com
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_string: mydestination: testmail.com ~? localhost
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: match_list_match: testmail.com: no match
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: maps_find: virtual_alias_maps: @testmail.com: not found
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: mail_addr_find: otheruser@testmail.com -> (not found)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: before input_transp_cleanup: cleanup flags = enable_header_body_filter enable_automatic_bcc enable_address_mapping enable_milters
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: after input_transp_cleanup: cleanup flags = enable_header_body_filter enable_automatic_bcc enable_address_mapping
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: name_mask: sendmail
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: name_mask: verify
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: connect to subsystem public/cleanup
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: queue_id
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: queue_id
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: 64FFA85196
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: (end)
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: send attr flags = 178
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: 64FFA85196: client=unknown[192.168.0.15]
Sep  4 18:34:16 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250 2.1.5 Ok
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>

Sep  4 18:35:40 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: < unknown[192.168.0.15]: data
Sep  4 18:35:40 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
subject: Test mail
Test message
.

Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/cleanup[9488]: 64FFA85196: message-id=<>
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: status
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: status
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: 0
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: reason
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: reason
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute value: (end)
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: input attribute name: (end)
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/smtpd[9402]: > unknown[192.168.0.15]: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 64FFA85196
Sep  4 18:36:43 relaysmtp postfix/qmgr[9399]: 64FFA85196: from=<username@domain.com>, size=225, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  4 18:36:55 relaysmtp postfix/smtp[9520]: 64FFA85196: SASL authentication failed; server smtp.office365.com[191.232.101.210] said: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [FR1PR80CA0078.lamprd80.prod.outlook.com]
Sep  4 18:37:06 relaysmtp postfix/smtp[9520]: 64FFA85196: SASL authentication failed; server smtp.office365.com[191.232.104.2] said: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [RO1P152CA0065.LAMP152.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

It seems postfix isn't even using sasl_passwd.db file generated with postmap.

What am i missing?

Thanks for help

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue due to no Linux environment, but I have found a topic which you can reference: https://secopsmonkey.com/mail-relaying-postfix-through-office-365.html

Comment: I follow the instructions and the result is the same

Comment: FYI, I tried with another account from same domain and the authentication is made and i can send emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with another account and the authentication works and the messages can be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

when you reload postfix, can you see anything missing in /var/log/mail or maillog file from postfix? In some cases it tells you what is missing. If you only see it is reloading fine, then you probably have to check master.cf file and try to commented out:

```
 #-o smtp_fallback_relay=
```

Also you can see what is live postfix configuration by doing "postconf -n"

Any changes made, require "postmap filename" for db files to be regenerated and postfix reloaded. Different to alias.db, use "postalias alias" to regenerate alias.db